# ZeroMQ Low Level API and Exceptions

Tags: zeromq

The documentation for the [low level ZeroMQ API](http://api.zeromq.org/) is clear with respect to the API functions return values, and how to use them to detect errors.

My question is: may I also assume that all of the these low level API functions do not throw any exception?

(I tried to figure out the correct answer by reading the documentation, but did not see any information regarding exceptions.)

Comment: The low level API is a C API. The C language does not support exceptions.

Comment: As @rveerd says the API is presented as a C API, which doesn't have exceptions. `libzmq` is actually written in C++ with a C shim around it, and C++ does support exceptions. However, it would be perverse if the C++ were written in such a way that an exception was raised and not wholly handled within `libzmq` and returned to the caller as a return value. So the low level functions do throw exceptions (`zmq_poller_add()` is one example), but this is caught within `libzmq` and dealt with; you shouldn't see any. It does mean `libzmq` has to be compiled with exceptions enabled.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I see that `zmq_poller_add()` catches `bad_alloc` and translates it to a C-style return code. But there are several places where `ZMQ_MAP_INSERT_OR_EMPLACE` and `ZMQ_PUSH_OR_EMPLACE_BACK` are used, and these can throw exceptions that are not catched, as far as I can see.

Comment: @Eliezer I think those boil down to STL map emplace_*. If those do throw exceptions, it looks like those indeed are not caught. These would be examples where the exception bubbles up to the top, and would result in a process termination. However, I think this is relatively ignorable; the only circumstance I can see why the exception would be thrown is if there were no memory left for whatever allocations the map emplace needs, and if that is the case then that's a situation that is difficult to recover from; termination might be the best outcome.